# How to get more information on what my OperationalError is

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm playing with sqlite3 binding in python, and pretty new to it. When my program runs:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO UpdateTypes (name) VALUES (?), (?), (?), (?), (?)',
    ('battery', 'missing', 'rssi', 'hear', 'status'))
```

I get the following:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

Which confuses me, because to test out, I opened `sqlite3` own a play database, and was able to execute:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO UpdateTypes (name) VALUES ('battery'), ('missing'), ('rssi'), ('hear'), ('status');
```

just fine.

So I need to figure this out, and an answer to what's wrong with what I did is welcome.

But what I'm **really** interested in, is how one gets more in depth information on what's wrong. For example, is there an sqlite3 module facility I can use to just run the substitution engine to see what the actual sql it's building is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to specify multiple records in a single `INSERT` statement was added in SQLite 3.7.11.

Your `sqlite3` command-line tool is new enough; the version of SQLite included in Python is not (check `SELECT sqlite_version();`).

Comment: Thank you! Wouldn't have thought to check that at all. I'm still curious if there's a way to to configure the python module to emit traces of what it's sending to the sqlite binding.